# For loop inside a method : TypeError positional arguments

Tags: python, class, for-loop, tkinter, typeerror

I'm trying to create a simple Gui with tkinter using classes.
But I don't really understand how to make the for-loop work inside the `count` method, could anyone tell me where should I add the missing argument?

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.container1 = Frame(master)
        self.container1.pack()
        self.button1 = Button(self.container1, text="count")
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.count)
        self.button1.pack()

    def count(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.button1["text"] = str(i)
            time.sleep(1)


root = Tk()
Myapp = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 2):

When you bind an event, a positional argument `event` is provided to the callback function.

Change your `count` method to this:

```
def count(self, event):
```

---

You will also need to get rid of `time.sleep(1)` since `.sleep()` is a blocking call, which means that it will block the tkinter mainloop which will cause your program to not respond.

Comment: So i have to use event as a positional argument anytime i define a function in where there is a variable? And what if there's more than one? And also , could you suggest me a way to replace time.sleep()? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your function has to except a positional argument since tkinter's event binding (when you wrote `self.button1.bind("...", self.count)`) automatically passes an event argument to the callback function, it doesn't have to be named `event`, it can be just this `def count(self, _):`. And for replacing time.sleep(), try searching for tkinter's root.after() method, if you're still having trouble, I can write a solution when I have the time.